# view values used by function boot to bootstrap estimates

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I have written the code below to obtain a bootstrap estimate of a mean.  My objective is to view the numbers selected from the data set, ideally in the order they are selected, by the function `boot` in the `boot` package.

The data set only contains three numbers: 1, 10, and 100 and I am only using two bootstrap samples.

The estimated mean is `23.5` and the `R` code below indicates that the six numbers included one '1', four '10' and one '100'.  However, there are 30 possible combinations of those numbers that would have resulted in a mean of 23.5.

Is there a way for me to determine which of those 30 possible combinations is the combination that actually appeared in the two bootstrap samples?

```
library(boot)

set.seed(1234)

dat <- c(1, 10, 100)
av  <- function(dat, i) { sum(dat[i])/length(dat[i]) }
av.boot <- boot(dat, av, R = 2)
av.boot
#
# ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
#
#
# Call:
# boot(data = dat, statistic = av, R = 2)
#
#
# Bootstrap Statistics :
#     original  bias    std. error
# t1*       37   -13.5    19.09188
#

mean(dat) + -13.5 
# [1] 23.5

# The two samples must have contained one '1', four '10' and one '100',
# but there are 30 possibilities.
# Which of these 30 possible sequences actual occurred?

# This code shows there must have been one '1', four '10' and one '100'
# and shows the 30 possible combinations

my.combos <- expand.grid(V1  = c(1, 10, 100),
                         V2  = c(1, 10, 100),
                         V3  = c(1, 10, 100),
                         V4  = c(1, 10, 100),
                         V5  = c(1, 10, 100),
                         V6  = c(1, 10, 100))

my.means <- apply(my.combos, 1, function(x) {( (x[1] + x[2] + x[3])/3 + (x[4] + x[5] + x[6])/3 ) / 2 })

possible.samples <- my.combos[my.means == 23.5,]
dim(possible.samples)

n.1   <- rowSums(possible.samples == 1)
n.10  <- rowSums(possible.samples == 10)
n.100 <- rowSums(possible.samples == 100)

n.1[1]
n.10[1]
n.100[1]

length(unique(n.1))   == 1
length(unique(n.10))  == 1
length(unique(n.100)) == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can determine the numbers sampled and the order in which they are sampled with the code below.  You have to extract the function `ordinary.array` from the `boot` package and paste that function into your `R` code.  Then specify the values for `n`, `R` and `strata`, where `n` is the number of observations in the data set and `R` is the number of replicate samples you want.

I do not know how general this approach is, but it worked with a couple of simple examples I tried, including the example below.

```
library(boot)

set.seed(1234)

dat <- c(1, 10, 100, 1000)
av  <- function(dat, i) { sum(dat[i])/length(dat[i]) }
av.boot <- boot(dat, av, R = 3)
av.boot
#
# ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
#
#
# Call:
# boot(data = dat, statistic = av, R = 3)
#
#
# Bootstrap Statistics :
#     original  bias    std. error
# t1*   277.75  -127.5    132.2405
# 
# 

mean(dat) + -127.5
# [1] 150.25

# boot:::ordinary.array

ordinary.array <- function (n, R, strata) 
{
    inds <- as.integer(names(table(strata)))
    if (length(inds) == 1L) {
        output <- sample.int(n, n * R, replace = TRUE)
        dim(output) <- c(R, n)
    }
    else {
        output <- matrix(as.integer(0L), R, n)
        for (is in inds) {
            gp <- seq_len(n)[strata == is]
            output[, gp] <- if (length(gp) == 1) 
                rep(gp, R)
            else bsample(gp, R * length(gp))
        }
    }
    output
}

# I think the function ordinary.array determines which elements 
# of the data are sampled in each of the R samples

set.seed(1234)
ordinary.array(n=4,R=3,1)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    3    1    3
# [2,]    3    4    1    3
# [3,]    3    3    3    3
#
# which equals:

((1+100+1+100) / 4  +  (100+1000+1+100) / 4  +  (100+100+100+100) / 4) / 3

# [1] 150.25
```